# Versioning your Model objects in Microsoft Web API 2 (REST, MVC)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

We have a REST API which already uses "/v1/" in the controller routes and we're planning to create a "/v2/" path and also take advantage Web API 2.  I was able to find a lot of information about versioning your controllers (attribute routing, custom resolvers, etc.) but one thing I have not been able to find any articles about is versioning your **Model** objects (a.k.a. data transfer objects).  How are people versioning their **Model** objects?

In our codebase and problem domain, the controllers are "simple" (CRUD, really) and it's the Model objects which encode our domain expertise and upon which our core business logic operates.  (I suspect this is true for many applications, so it's strange that most of the web articles about Web API 2 and versioning focus on controllers and elide concerns about the Model objects as if they'll take care of themselves.)

In a perfect world, I'd like to be able to just use the same classes for both API versions, and put attributes on properties to include or exclude them, things like "version 1 only", "version 2+ only", "deprecated in version 2", etc.  I think I could implement this with a custom serializer that looks for attribute classes I create, but I want to know if there's built-in support for this or an open source library for it before I roll my own.

Another possible approach would be to derive the version 2 model classes from the version 1 model classes, but I could only add that way and not be able to remove anything.  I could derive both the version 1 and the version 2 classes from a base class, but any of these inheritance-based approaches will require A) refactoring where classes are plus B) a factory pattern so that the internals can create the correct derived type.  I'd like to avoid this, but would still prefer it over code duplication.

I suppose another approach is we could hide our real Model objects and copy their values into "dumb" data transfer objects at the interface.  This approach is simple and would have maximum flexibility, but would also maximize the work.

Is there an option I've missed?  What approach are other people using?

Comment: On one project (RoR to C# conversion) I planned to use the last one where we had model that represented database structure and business logic, and then had ModelView classes that could modify what about that model was actually returned (or the model itself).  PoC showed it as viable approach in our case, but project got cancelled before we got to implement it for real.  Another option is that XmlSerializer understand a specially named property that tells whether to serialize a given property (by naming convention, can't recall at the moment), which you can use to control by versioning.

Comment: Regarding your second suggestion (which is actually the approach I'm favoring) - how does the serializer know which API version it is serializing for?  All I can think of is to actually use a property of the DTO itself to indicate that; conveniently our app architect *already* included an "ApiVersion" property on all of the DTOs, which I could co-opt for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, that information would have to come from some context and your model would need to know for which version it is being serialized, and what needs to be serialized for that version.  How do you version your models?  Each model just knows about its own history and how to behave based on what it is told its contextual version is?

Comment: Good point.  Whether I have distinct types of models or optional model properties, I'll have to a) indicate to the app internals what kind of model I want back, and b) model behavior will have to be correct per version.  If I have a separate controller class for each api version, then the controller itself would know what version it is and could take correct action, and if I had a shared controller implementation I could get it out of URI component.

Comment: B/w, another way to do it (and I've never tried it, so could be a totally not doable idea) is to simply have several "apps" which are just versions of the same, mounted under different base urls with different versions.  Then your Models need to know nothing about versioning, and you simply have your code branches for various versions, build all, publish all, and keep your code simple, yet have server provide all various versions you had in the past (and still able to fix bugs in older versions with proper tagging/branching strategy).  That would meet my "KISS" design pattern requirements :)

Comment: well, in my case what i did was intercepted the response and excluded the  properties which was not required for a specific api version. so, now you have one model class and just remove the property from response which is not required.